# Odoo pivot view styling

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

Is it possible to show empty place in pivot view as 0.

```
        Quantity
Sales1      1
Sales2     
Sales3     2
```

When Sales2 quantity is not set, show 0 instead of empty.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Odoo will not set the cell value if it is [undefined](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/pivot/pivot_renderer.js#L292)

You can override the model [_computeRows](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/pivot/pivot_model.js#L600) function and append a default value

***Example:***

```
if (aggregates === undefined) {
    aggregates = 0.0;
}
```